Error connecting to mongoose from express app
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const app = express();

mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://u=username:passowword@cluster0.40rthzc.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=Cluster0");

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello");});

 app.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log("App is running on port 8080");}); 

I have tried everything from selecting different connection string checking and changing passwords. Modified the ip access. But nothing worked.
The error it shows is this -
Error: querySrv ECONNREFUSED _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.40rthzc.mongodb.net
at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (node:internal/dns/promises:275:17) {
errno: undefined,
code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
syscall: 'querySrv',
hostname: '_mongodb._tcp.cluster0.40rthzc.mongodb.net'
 }

This is a sample code only for demonstrating the actual problem
